# Regular expression not working correctly through input via getline()

Tags: c++, regex

I need to validate a string that is at least 5 characters long, contains at least one upper-case letter, at least one lower-case letter, at least one digit and no other characters except the dash and the underscore. I've tested this in other languages and it apparently works:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z_\-]{5,}$
```

However, in C++, this simple test program validates strings such as "AasdA" as correct input. I know I am missing something glaringly obvious, but after much research I cannot tell what is wrong. Maybe it's something to do with the way getline() stores strings. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string test;
    do {
        cout << "Test: ";
        getline(cin, test);

        if (regex_match(test, regex("^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z_\-]{5,}$"))) {
            cout << "True." << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "False." << endl;
        }
    } while (test != "");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler? GCC doesn't implement `regex` yet.

Comment: @uk4321 it has now, late 4.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double the backslashes in your string constant:

```
if (regex_match(test, regex("^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z_\\-]{5,}$"))) {
```

Comment: Or, if C++11, use raw strings: `R"(regex)"`.